# Можно ли подключиться по ssh извне ssh к хосту, с которого было ssh соединение?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh

Имеется два хоста. С одного хоста на другой делается ssh-соединение.

На удаленном хосте имеется директория `~/repository`, к которой возможен конкурентный доступ еще десятками других хостов. Для решения этой проблемы на удаленном хосте также имеется файл `~/repisotory.lock`, на который все хосты вынуждены делать блокировку на время доступа к директории `~/repository`, чтобы решить проблему конкуренции.

Блокировка осуществляется такой командой на удаленном хосте:

```
(
   flock -n 9
   # ... commands executed under lock ...
) 9>~/repisotory.lock
```

Моя задача требует возможность скачать данные из удаленной директории `~/repository` на локальный хост. Но это скачивание должны быть под блокировкой файла `~/repisotory.lock` на удаленном хосте.

Как мне скопировать файл с удаленной директории `~/repository` на локальный хост, используя уже установленное ssh соединение? Команда копирования должна быть на месте `# ... commands executed under lock ...`, чтобы она полностью была под блокировкой.

Для копирования файлов по ssh я использую rsync, хотя точно такая же проблема будет с любой командой.

Если я пропишу такую команду:

```
(
   flock -n 9
   rsync -a ~/repository айпи-локального-хоста:~
) 9>~/repisotory.lock
```

Тогда rsync откроет новое ssh соединение, заново попросит аутентификацию. Но ведь соединение уже имеется с локального хоста на удаленный, как его использовать?

Comment: Ну документацию конечно же мы не читаем. Во-первых, посмотрите про понятие "мастер-соединения" в SSH, во-вторых, понятие реверсного соеденения (`-R`) там же, в-третьих, `rsync -e ssh ...`, в-четвёртых, `ssh -e ...`. Непонятен  вызов `flock` в сочетании с `rsync`. Что он решает?

Comment: моя задача была в том, чтобы сделать блокировку удаленной директории, откуда rsync качает данные. для этого нужно 1) создать блокировку 2) вызвать команду rsync 3) снять блокировку. файл lock должен находиться на удаленном хосте. но в такой конфигурации rsync придется запускать в обратную сторону с удаленного хоста на локальный, потому что команда rsync должна быть внутри блока shell-кода  `( flock -x 200; rsync -a src user@host1:~/dest ) 200>write.loc`. но потом я нашел костыльное решение с помощью `--rsync-path`, и потребность в обратном ssh соединении отпала

Comment: но научный интерес у меня все равно остался. если вы знаете как сделать обратное соединение ssh, поделитесь пожалуйста. в инете предлагают создавать какие-то ssh тоннели с дополнительными портами. но я не понимаю, зачем это надо, ведь ssh соединение уже имеется. как его использовать для обратной связи удаленного хоста с локальным, например, для передачи файла командой rsync

Comment: Вы видимо не понимаете как работает `rsync`. Ещё раз, зачем нужна блокировка?

Comment: @0andriy блокировка нужна по условиям моей задачи. для вас это просто данность должна быть, что она нужна. если сильно интересно: я делаю pull deployment, мне нужно блокировать удаленную директорию, если в нее прямо сейчас делается отправка обновления. без блокировки команда rsync может скачать только частично отправленное обновление.

Comment: @0andriy я переписал свой вопрос. надеюсь, что теперь будет понятнее, зачем мне необходим `flock`.

Comment: Понятно, вы добиваетесь атомарности там, где в принципе это трудно гарантировать. Из чего такого вы делаете *pull deployment*, что не позволяет вам сделать это атомарно? Для Git это же совсем просто, для других должно быть что-то подобное на стороне клиента.

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос я дал в комментариях выше.

Comment: `Из чего такого вы делаете pull deployment...?` - из обычной директории, это не git репозиторий. это просто директория с файлами. атомарности добиться можно с помощью flock. я уже дал ответ на свой вопрос, который решает проблему атомарности. но это решение без обратного ssh соединения

Comment: Понятно, есть разные способы добиться того, что вы желаете, без `flock`. Вы выбрали с ним, удачи! А упорство нечтения документации ни к чему хорошему не приведёт :)

Answer (score 1):

Это не ответ на мой вопрос, но это решает мою проблему:

```sh
rsync -a --rsync-path="flock -s ~/reposotry.lock rsync" айпи удаленного хоста:~/repository ~
```